# How to let player chose to be X or O as well as an option to play the game again?

Tags: c, conditional-statements, tic-tac-toe

So I need some help in this Tic-Tac-Toe game. I have almost everything working correctly I just need to add on some features. Those features include: 1.) allowing the player to choose whether they want to play as X or O in the game, and 2.) giving the option for the players to replay the game if they wish. I've gotten the base mechanics of the game to work out nicely, I just can't figure out how to add these features into the code. I've started to "lay the foundation" for the first feature (giving the player the option to choose their mark). (Honestly, I'm just really tired from studying for the past 48hrs for finals and I could really use a helping hand here). Here is my full code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <conio.h>


int checkwin(char gridspace[]);
void gameboard(char gridspace[]);
int gameLoop(int choice, int player, char gridspace[], char mark);

void main(void)
{
char grid[10] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
int player = 1, victory, choice;

char mark, player1, player2;
int markchoice;
do // game loop start
{
    gameboard(grid); // draws the game board
    if (player % 2) // player turn conditional
    {
        player = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        player = 2;
    }
    printf("Player 1, choose which mark you would like to play as (1=X or 2=O)\n"); // asks the player to choose a mark
    scanf("%c", &markchoice);
    if (markchoice == 1) // mark choice conditional
    {
        mark = 'X';            
    }
    else
    {
        mark = 'O';             
    }
    printf("Player %d, enter the number of the place you wish to place your mark:  ", player); // asks the player to place their mark on a space
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    if (player == 1) // mark type (X or O) placement conditional 
    {
        mark;
    }
    else
    {
        mark;
    }
    gameLoop(choice, player, grid, mark); // calls the main game function that houses the conditionals 
    
    victory = checkwin(grid); // checks the state of the game (if its in progress, a draw, or a player has achieved victory.

    player++;
} while (victory == -1); //end of game loop

gameboard(grid); // redraws the game board

if (victory == 1) // conditional that breaks the game loop and gives a result (victory or draw)
{
    printf("==>\aPlayer %d win ", --player);
}
else 
{
    printf("==>\aGame draw");
    getch();
}
return 0; 
} // end of main
int gameLoop(int choice,int player, char gridspace[], char mark) // function for game loop 
decisionals
{
if (choice == 1 && gridspace[1] == '1')
    gridspace[1] = mark;

else if (choice == 2 && gridspace[2] == '2')
    gridspace[2] = mark;

else if (choice == 3 && gridspace[3] == '3')
    gridspace[3] = mark;

else if (choice == 4 && gridspace[4] == '4')
    gridspace[4] = mark;

else if (choice == 5 && gridspace[5] == '5')
    gridspace[5] = mark;

else if (choice == 6 && gridspace[6] == '6')
    gridspace[6] = mark;

else if (choice == 7 && gridspace[7] == '7')
    gridspace[7] = mark;

else if (choice == 8 && gridspace[8] == '8')
    gridspace[8] = mark;

else if (choice == 9 && gridspace[9] == '9')
    gridspace[9] = mark;

else
{
    printf("Invalid move, input a different number.");

    player--;
    getch();
}
return 1;
}// end of game loop function

int checkwin(char gridspace[]) // check win function 
{
if (gridspace[1] == gridspace[2] && gridspace[2] == gridspace[3])
    return 1;

else if (gridspace[4] == gridspace[5] && gridspace[5] == gridspace[6])
    return 1;

else if (gridspace[7] == gridspace[8] && gridspace[8] == gridspace[9])
    return 1;

else if (gridspace[1] == gridspace[4] && gridspace[4] == gridspace[7])
    return 1;

else if (gridspace[2] == gridspace[5] && gridspace[5] == gridspace[8])
    return 1;

else if (gridspace[3] == gridspace[6] && gridspace[6] == gridspace[9])
    return 1;

else if (gridspace[1] == gridspace[5] && gridspace[5] == gridspace[9])
    return 1;

else if (gridspace[3] == gridspace[5] && gridspace[5] == gridspace[7])
    return 1;

else if (gridspace[1] != '1' && gridspace[2] != '2' && gridspace[3] != '3' && 
    gridspace[4] != '4' && gridspace[5] != '5' && gridspace[6] != '6' && gridspace[7]
    != '7' && gridspace[8] != '8' && gridspace[9] != '9') // if all spaces are filled but no 
three match then the game is a draw

    return 0;
else // if no three spaces match and empty spaces still exist then the game is still in 
progress. 
    return  -1;
} // end of check win function

void gameboard(char gridspace[]) // game board function.
{
system("cls");
printf("\n\n\tTic Tac Toe\n\n");
printf("Enter a number for where you wish to place your mark");
printf("Player 1 (X)  -  Player 2 (O)\n\n\n");


printf("     |     |     \n");
printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c \n", gridspace[1], gridspace[2], gridspace[3]);

printf("_____|_____|_____\n");
printf("     |     |     \n");

printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c \n", gridspace[4], gridspace[5], gridspace[6]);

printf("_____|_____|_____\n");
printf("     |     |     \n");

printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c \n", gridspace[7], gridspace[8], gridspace[9]);

printf("     |     |     \n\n");
} // end of board drawing funciton.
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. So thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

to allow multiple rounds you can add another while loop outside the game one in order to reset all the stats and restart the game until player decides to stop(you can use a scanf to check for y/n).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).